# Как проверить ошибку 404?

Tags: php, if

На странице может быть ошибка header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");

как проверить по условию if есть ли такая ошибка на странице?

Comment: возможно вопрос поставлен неверно?
например: "Если URI некорректный как возвратить заголовок 404?"

Comment: `if (http_response_code() === 404) ...`